# Replace static data in HTML page with dynamic one from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, mysql

I have an HTML code for my asp.net web application is that when i press the button Submit it calls a function to read what's in the bd and load it into an html page with certain template and I want to know how to replace static data in the original HTML file with dynamic ones from mysql database using C#. In my code I did read the input file and i did create an output file to write in as shown below:

```
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filepath/inputcv.html");
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("filepath/outputcv.html");
```

This is a part of the code i need to replace the content of this paragraph by the one in my database

```
<div class="sectionContent">
    <p>@1</p>
</div>
```

I saw this code and I wanted to do like it but I don't know how to write the query in it

```
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("path/to/file.txt");
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("path/to/outfile.txt");
     string sLine = sr.ReadLine();
         for (; sLine; sLine = sr.ReadLine() )
        {
         sLine = "{" + sLine.Replace(" ", ", ") + "}";
        sw.Write(sLine);
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the contents of the HTML file loaded into a string that you are going to write back out?  Or is this on the active ASPX page?

Comment: Did you write the portion that gets the data from the database?  Is data to be inserted ready in a string?

Comment: With C# + MVC, creating a dynamic page is the natural way to go. it is so easy that I am not understand why you don't use it?
If you don't use MVC, you can still use "standalone" Razor Engine with a model and creating your dynamic content. e.g. https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to store the external data in either text file, or XML file, or database and use it for dynamic update of HTML page content. The first requirement to clarify: what will work as the "filter" for that "dynamic" data updates, in other words, which part of your code will perform dynamic updates the select statement (in case of mySQL)? If that statement remains the same, then it means that underlying data is changing, but what is controlling that changes in DB? And what is the desirable data refreshment rate of page updates? This should be clarified first before proceeding to actual code.

Hope this will help. My best, AB

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I come up with based upon what you have provided.  Please comment with more details if this is not enough.

```
        string strHTMLPage = "";
        string strNewHTMLPage = "";
        int intStartIndex = 0;
        int intEndIndex = 0;
        string strNewDataToBeInserted = "Assumes you loaded this string with the
                                         data you want inserted";

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filepath/inputcv.html");
        strHTMLPage = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();

        intStartIndex = strHTMLPage.IndexOf("<div class=\"sectionContent\">", 0) + 28;
        intStartIndex = strHTMLPage.IndexOf("<p>", intStartIndex) + 3;

        intEndIndex = strHTMLPage.IndexOf("</p>", intStartIndex);

        strNewHTMLPage = strHTMLPage.Substring(0, intStartIndex);
        strNewHTMLPage += strNewDataToBeInserted;
        strNewHTMLPage += strHTMLPage.Substring(intEndIndex);


        StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("filepath/outputcv.html", false, Encoding.UTF8);
        sw.Write(strNewHTMLPage);
        sw.Close();
```